# What axioms does this definition fail to satisfy?

Tags: inner-products

For two polynomials, f,g

If I defined inner product of these two polys to be $$(f\cdot g) = \left|\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\right|$$
(does this satisfy inner product?

I think it is not.

1. $x\cdot y=y\cdot x$ ok
2. $x\cdot(y+z)=x\cdot y+x\cdot z$ it fails to satisfy
3. $c(x\cdot y)=(cx)\cdot y$ it fails to satisfy
4. $x\cdot x>0$  if $x\neq0$

This is what I concluded and I have a proof for each case that does not satisfy it.

I just want to make sure that I did check it right, or Anybody tell me the answer?

Comment: In point 4, you have a typo, that should be $x\neq 0$.

Comment: For point 3, you might state why not (e.g. certain values of $c$).  Indeed, some explanation for each conclusion might help.

Comment: For all c < 0  This is what I stated

Answer (score 2):

Actually, $(u|v)=\int_0^1 u(x)v(x)dx$ is an inner product on polynomials (and also on continuous functions, for example), and [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) with it yields [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) if you integrate on $[-1,1]$, and [shifted Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials) if you integrate on $[0,1]$.

However, with the absolute value, it's not an inner product, and the reason is that the absolute value is not linear, as you point out.

It's enough to show counterexamples with constant polynomials, and with your inner product $(u|v)=\left|\int_0^1 u(x)v(x)dx\right|$:

$$(1|-1)=(1|1)=1\neq-(1|1)=-1$$
$$(1|2-1)=(1|1)=1\neq (1|2)+(1|-1)=3$$

The other two axioms or however easily proved true.

Comment: So, what I mentioned above is correct? and the other axioms 1, 4 does work for it?

Comment: @dabid Yes. The first is trivial, and the fourth is a consequence of the fact that without the absolute value it's an inner product, but in case you don't know already the fact, consider the polynomial $u$ as a (continuous) function in $(u|u)$, then the integral of a continuous positive function is null iff the function is null, hence $(u|u)=0 \implies u=0$.